# How to replace a word in MS Word to a table by VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have opened the MS word using create object then ,I have to search for a word and replace it with a table.I was able to build a table using VBA.
But, I need to replace that word (Matched) with a Table and later fill the table as per cell.
This is my code:-

```
Dim MyApp As New Word.Application
Dim MyDoc As Word.Document

Set MyDoc = MyApp.Documents.Add 

MyApp.Visible = True
MyDoc.Activate 
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
.Text = "blue"
.Forward = True
.Execute
If .Found = True Then .Parent.Bold = True
End With
MyApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=MyApp.Selection.Range, numrows:=5, numcolumns:=5 

MyApp.ActiveDocument.Save 
MyApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help if you do more object-oriented programming, instead of relying on "ActiveDocument", etc.

Start by defining a `Range` object that represents the `Document.Content`.  The `Find.Execute` method, if returns `True`, will redefine this `Range` object to the found word.  So you can use this as the `Range` argument in the `Tables.Add` method.

**Update from comments** I realize that you are instantiating Word, and then adding a new (blank) document. As expected, the `Find.Execute` will not find anything in this document.  Instead, I revised to specifically open a document from a known file path.

```
'Create a new instance of MS Word
Dim MyApp As New Word.Application
Dim MyDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRange As Word.Range

'Open an existing Word file:
Set MyDoc = MyApp.Documents.Open("c:\myfile.docx") '# REVISE AS NEEDED

'Make MS Word visible:
MyApp.Visible = True

'Assign the wdRange variable to the document's Content
Set wdRange = MyDoc.Content

'Use the Find method within wdRange:
With wdRange.Find
    .Text = "blue"
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        .Parent.Bold = True
        ' Since Find.Execute resizes the wdRange to the "found" word, we can
        '  use this wdRange as the Range argument for Tables.Add:
        MyDoc.Tables.Add Range:=wdRange, numrows:=5, numcolumns:=5
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Did you change the text from the `Find` to be the word you're looking for?  In my code, I searched for the word `"turtles"`.

Comment: I revised to use the word `"blue"`.

Comment: Also see update above, you're attempting to run this on an empty/blank document (`Documents.Add` is always an empty file).  I changed that so you can specify a file to open, and then it should work I think.

Comment: @ David What is MyApp in the above code. is it the word application .Could you update the above code

Comment: Yes, `MyApp` is the same as you created it, but I will include that line of code.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio .Aspx page with <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript"> U r Code</Script>.I am getting an Error.what compiler are you using.Do u know any complier that has intellisence.

Comment: You indicate in the question title and tags that your problem is with `VBA` -- which is different than `VBScript`.  I think there are similarities between the two, so if you would indicate which line raises the error perhaps I can help, but I am not an ASP or VBScript developer; I'm using `VBA` from the hosted applications MS Excel and MS Word, and have run this code from Excel and a slightly modified version which ran initially from MS Word.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out VbA and VBScript are different.Thanks a lot for u r effort